# Wifi file transfer between windows-windows and/or windows-android

Tags: file-management

As WiFi softwares are much harder to use and are not plug and play type like Bluetooth or wired connections, I am having problems transferring files over the WiFi ( I have no secondary wifi sources or devices besides my laptop and another laptop/ android device).so,

1) Can you guys suggest a quick way to transfer files over android- windows and vice versa? I have ES file browser which I suppose supports it. Any tips?

2) the same for windows-windows transfer. I have windows 7.

Please note I am not well versed with concepts like router DNS proxy so it would be very helpful if you suggest in a layman like manner. :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I use [AirDroid](http://www.airdroid.com/) for this. You can get it on [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid&hl=en).

From the app's description:

> Manage your Android devices on the web, all over the air.

- No USB cable required.
- No driver installation required.
- WiFi network or Internet.

Answer (score 3):

I use [IPMessenger](http://ipmsg.org/index.html.en) in windows.

It uses pop-up style interface.

You do not need internet connection. If you are just connected to a wifi network, it works.

**Features:**

- Serverless message communication
- Fast file/folder transfer
- Image embeded message, desktop (area specified) capture
- Message encrytion(RSA2048bit + AES256bit) and sign/verify (PKCS#1-v1_5)
- Supports any number of computers
- Resume capability also

[IPMessenger for Android also available.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aob.android.ipmsg&hl=en)

Comment: Tutorial on IPMessenger : http://techiegenie.blogspot.in/2014/02/send-files-or-messages-to-any-computer.html

Answer (score 2):

Set up a shared folder that you can drop files into on the remote machine - unfortunately how you do this varies between OSs and even between versions of OS in some cases.  Then you need to validate the other computer - again this varies.

For Windows 7, (As I am on Linux this is from memory), -

- You need to go into network and sharing centre by right clicking on the network icon on the task bar,
- ensure that the network that you are on is set to either Home or Work - not Public,
- turn on folder sharing,
- select the folders that you would like to share - a lot of people have an outgoing and incoming folder as it makes things easier to keep track of.
- You may also have to specify the individual folders as shared by right clicking on them in file explorer.

You could also consider buying a wi-fi network storage device, this will give you a lot of additional storage that can be shared between computers and act as a back-up in case of problems.  You can either get a Wi-Fi enabled device which has its own WiFi or you can connect a network drive to your router.  In most places they are now very reasonably priced and usually come with good set-up instructions.

One of the easiest methods is to use a system such as Google Drive that is cross platform and does not require the computers to be co-located.  Then if you wish to transfer a file you just drop it into the Google Drive folder.  There are many other services that offer the same functionality but keep in mind that you are sharing via the internet so there are possible security issues but there are some with opening up a shared folder on your machine anyway.

Comment: Thank you . But I do not want to use the internet at all because it is slow and costly here. I have windows 7 in both laptops. I have turned off windows firewall which sometimes cause problems. Can you please give any step by step instructions on what to do next? :)